# Почему у функции scanf_s в Visual Studio при использовании "%s" прекращается работа в языке Си

Tags: c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Почему у функции scanf_s в Visual Studio 2013 при использовании "%s" прекращается работа в языке Си .

```
char name[40];
scanf_s("%s", name);
```

Тут, когда в консоли ввёл данные, нажимаю энтер, и вижу сообщение "Прекращение работы".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что `scanf_s` требует указания размера всех передаваемых ей буферов.

```
scanf_s("%s", name, 40);
```

Comment: А как справится если будет scanf("%s %d", как тут писать?); если есть две переменые?

Comment: Пожалуйста, почитайте документацию.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w40768et%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Надо указать параметр `_countof (имя переменной куда считываешь)`, например:

```
scanf_s("%s",&name,_countof(name));
```

Comment: У `_countof` тип не тот, нужно unsigned передавать.