# C++ Почему недостаточно аргументов в scan_f?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

При осуществлении считывания данных столкнулся с предупреждением о недостаточности аргументов.
Выводит ошибку представленную ниже при попытке ввода данных в переменную `name1`
Мой исходный код представлено ниже.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;

char name1[9], name2[9], name3[9];

int main(void) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    /*Введение фактических данных*/
    scanf_s("%s",&name1);
    printf("%s",&name1);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Недостаточно аргументов для строки формата]
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: При вызове scanf_s нужно кроме строки формата и указателя (куда читать данные) нужно задавать еще размер блока данных.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440088/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%83-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-scanf-s-%D0%B2-visual-studio-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-s-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1

Comment: Почему бы, раз уж ставите тэг "c++", не использовать плюсплюсный ввод-вывод?

Comment: потому что эта функция c++.